# Y axes labels on the right as well in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, linechart

I'm just trying to add the same Y axes labels (4040,4050 etc..) on the right as well, on a Plotly chart. To make it simple, just mirror it.

This is a Plotly line chart.

This is quite simple to do on a matplotlib by using **plt.tick_params(labeltop=False,labelright=True)**

I'm using (import plotly.express as px)

**Just wondering if there was a straightforward way to do it on Plotly Line and Area chart as well?**
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have used approach of duplicating trace and setting it to use second yaxis.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y="GOOG")

# add another trace to carry second y-axis
fig.add_traces({**fig.to_dict()["data"][0], **{"yaxis": "y2"}})
# config second yaxis
fig.update_layout(
    {
        "yaxis2": {
            "side": "right",
        }
    }
)
```

[image]